# Finding a min() date for one column and then using this to join with other tables that have a date LESS than this date

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

In short, I have two tables:

(1) `pharmacy_claims` (columns: `user_id`, `date_service`, `claim_id`, `record_id`, `prescription`)

(2) `medical_claims`  (columns:  `user_id`, `date_service`, `provider`, `npi`, `cost`)

I want to find `user_id`'s in (1) that have a certain `prescription` value, find their earliest `date_service` (e.g. `min(date_service)`) and then use these `user_id`'s with their earliest date of service as a cohort to pull all of their associated data from (2). Basically I want to find all of their `medical_claims` data PRIOR to the first time they were prescribed a given prescription in `pharmacy_claims`.

`pharmacy_claims` looks something like this:

```
user_id | prescription | date_service
1           a             2018-05-01
1           a             2018-02-11
1           a             2019-10-11
1           b             2018-07-12
2           a             2019-01-02
2           a             2019-03-10
2           c             2018-04-11
3           c             2019-05-26
```

So for instance, if I was interested in prescription = 'a', I would only want user_id 1 and 2 returned, with dates 2018-02-11 and 2019-01-02, respectively. Then I would want to pull user_id 1 and 2 from the `medical_claims`, and get all of their data PRIOR to these respective dates.

The way I tried to go about this was to build out a temp table in the `pharmacy_claims` table to query the `user_id`'s that have a given medication, and then left join this back to the table to create a cohort of `user_id`'s with a `date_service`

Here's what I did:

(1) Pulled all of the relevant data from the main pharmacy claims table:

```
CREATE TABLE user.temp_pharmacy_claims AS
SELECT user_id, claim_id, record_id, date_service
FROM dw.pharmacyclaims 
WHERE date_service between '2018-01-01' and '2019-08-31'
```

This results in ~50,000 `user_id`'s

(2) Created a table with just the `user_id`'s a `min(date_service)`:

```
CREATE TABLE user.temp_pharmacy_claims_index AS
SELECT distinct user_id, min(date_service) AS Min_Date
FROM user.temp_pharmacy_claims
GROUP BY 1
```

(3) Created a final table (to get the desired cohort):

```
CREATE TABLE user.temp_pharmacy_claims_final_index AS
SELECT a.userid
FROM user.temp_pharmacy_claims  a
LEFT JOIN user.temp_pharmacy_claims_index b
ON a.user = b.user
WHERE  a.date_service < Min_Date
```

However, this gets me 0 results when there should be a few thousand. Is this set up correctly? It's probably not the most efficient approach, but it looks sound to me, so not sure what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want a correlated subquery:

```
select mc.*
from medical_claims mc
where mc.date_service < (select min(pc.date)
                         from pharmacy_claims pc
                         where pc.user_id = mc.user_id and 
                               pc.prescription = ?
                        );
```

Comment: I think this should work, but ideally I wanted to create a temp table of the user_id's and Min_Date so I could use as a sub-select (WHERE user_id in (select user_id from user.temp_pharmacy_claims_final_index. I tried to keep this example as simple as possible, but will need to do some sub-selecting down the road

Comment: @David . . . There is no need to create a temporary table, which just adds complexity to the solution.